# To find all functions which satisfy$f(x^3)+f^3(y)+f^3(z)=3xyz \\ \forall x+y+z=0$ and $x,y,z\in\mathbb R$

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

**Note:** $f^3(x)=f(x)^3$.

### Question:

Find all the functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfy $\forall x,y,z\in\mathbb R, x+y+z=0$, we have $f(x^3)+f^3(y)+f^3(z)=3xyz$.

---

#### My ideas:

> It is obvious that $f(x)=x$ is a solution. It is likely that $f(x)=x$ is the only solution.
>
> Let $x=0$, then $y=0$, we can find that $f(x^3)=f^3(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.
> So $f(x^3)+f(y^3)+f(z^3)=3xyz=x^3+y^3+z^3$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb R, x+y+z=0$.
>
> I think it is related to Cauchy's Functional Equation, which needs $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)\ \forall x,y\in\mathbb R$. However, I can't prove it.
>
> Maybe it is useful to prove $f$ is injective, but I have no idea.

Comment: There are multiple errors in your attempt. $f(x^3)=f^3(x)$ is not correct and $f(x)=x$ is not a solution.

Comment: First you let $x=0,y=0$ then say it holds for all real x? You just restricted x. Also $f(x^3) = f^3(x)$ holds for $f(x) = x$, but not for many other functions at all.

Comment: I'd start to prove some basic properties like $f(0)=0$ and $f$ being an odd function.

Answer (score 3):

I will show how we transform this into a Cauchy's functional equation (since this is what the poster attempts to do).

Take $x=y=z=0$, then $f(0)+2f(0)^3=0$. The only real solution is $f(0)=0$.

Take $x=0,z=-y$, then $f(y)^3+f(-y)^3=0$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $(-f(y))^3=f(-y)^3$ and hence $-f(y)=f(-y)$. This shows that $f$ is an odd function.

Take $z=0,y=-x$, then $f(x^3)+f(-x)^3=0$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus $f(x^3)=f(x)^3$ since $f$ is an odd function.

To sum up we have $f(x^3)+f(y^3)+f(z^3)=3xyz$ for $x+y+z=0$. In the following we need the identity $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$ for $x+y+z=0$, which is simply because $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx).$$

Now define $g(t)=f(t^3)-t^3$. Then $g$ is also an odd function and $g(0)=0$. We have $$g(x)+g(y)+g(z)=f(x^3)+f(y^3)+f(z^3)-(x^3+y^3+z^3)=0$$ if $x+y+z=0$. Therefore for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $g(x)+g(y)=-g(-x-y)=g(x+y)$, a Cauchy's functional equation.

Comment: Isn't it that when $x=y=z=0$, it should be that $f(0)^3+2f^3(0)=0$ (It woud be a circular argument if we assumed $f^3(0)=f(0)^3$)

Comment: We have $0=3xyz=f(0^3)+2f(0)^3=f(0)+2f(0)^3$. Maybe you had a typo in your comment?

Comment: It is that $f^3(0)=f(0)^3$ can also be not true. There is no implication where the above is true. The question with $x=y=z=0$ implies $f(0)+2f^3(0)=0$, not $f(0)+2f(0)^3$.

Comment: I comprehend the notation $f^3(x)$ as $(f(x))^3$. I guess you comprehend it as $f(f(f(x)))$?

Comment: I believe so that $f^3(x)=f(f(f(x)))$ as it shows the distinction between $f^3(x)$ and $f(x)^3$ which can be detrimental to the solutions yielded. Might as well query OP for this.

Comment: Well for me I usually use the notation as I comprehend. I will change my answer if OP clarifies notations.

Comment: @INvisibLE The questioner has edited his question. Now it explicitly says "Note: $f^3(x) = f(x)^3$".

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I believe my answer follows the notation from the questioner, i.e. $f^3(x)=(f(x))^3$.